# How can I Ignore onMouseOut after onClick function?

Tags: javascript

I have a `#myObject` element.

I'm trying to make `#myObject`'s background change to `#000` when mouse is hovered over it and make its background change back to `#ffff00` on hover out.

But I want to make `#myObject`'s background change to `#FFF` when a user clicks it.

I used 3 functions for onMouseOver, onMouseOut and onClick.

But after the user's click, the "onMouseOut" function is triggered.

How can I get the `onClick` background toggle to work after user hovers out of  `#myObject` after clicking it?

```
<div id="myObject" onMouseOver='objHover(this.id);' onMouseOut='objMouseOut(this.id);' onclick='objClick(this.id);'></div>

function objClick(id) {
    document.getElementById('captchaResposta').value = id;
    $('#'+ id).css('background','#FFF');
}

function objHover(id) {
    document.getElementById('captchaResposta').value = id;
    $('#'+ id).css('background','#000');
}

function objMouseOut(id) {
    document.getElementById('captchaResposta').value = id;
    $('.imagemCaptcha').css('background','#ffff00');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should help, it uses a variable `objSelected` to track the mouse click and the checks in the mouseOut function.  You would still need to figure out when to revert the object's color back to it's original color

```
<div id="myObject" onMouseOver='objHover(this.id);' onMouseOut='objMouseOut(this.id);' onclick='objClick(this.id);'></div>

var objSelected = false;

function objClick(id) {
    document.getElementById('captchaResposta').value = id;
    $('#'+ id).css('background','#FFF');
    objSelected = true;
}

function objHover(id) {
    document.getElementById('captchaResposta').value = id;
    $('#'+ id).css('background','#000');
}

function objMouseOut(id) {
    document.getElementById('captchaResposta').value = id;
    if (objSelected == false)
    {
        $('.imagemCaptcha').css('background','#ffff00');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the CSS `hover` pseudo-class to change the background, and use JavaScript only for a click event? That way, when the mouse leaves the element, it still maintains the color it had when clicked

```js
function objClick(id) {
  $("#myObject").css('background', '#FFF');
}
```

```css
#myObject {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffff00;
}
#myObject:hover {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myObject" onclick='objClick(this.id);'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"onMouseOver, onMouseOut and onClick."

I think you could use classes that you apply to the element (instead of changing the color) on the events. On click you can add a `clicked` class (or whatever name you want to use). Then, on the mouseout event you can check if the selector has the `clicked` class: if not, then you go and add the `mouseout` class (with its corresponding background color). It will do the job just fine.